# How to fix unknown certificate on CharlesProxy

Tags: http-headers, request-headers, charles-proxy, response-headers

I have been trying to obtain traffic from Discord mobile APP (discordapp.com) using CharlesProxy, I have installed the certificates, set SSL proxy configuration to obtain discord traffic.
(I'm experimenting with Discord version 9.6.4)

> [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btLWB.png)
> [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OO90.png)
> [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4VKh.png)

However, this is what I get on CharlesProxy, this error pops up: An unknown issue occurred processing the ssl certificate (unknown_certificate)

I downloaded the certificate from the official website, for Android.

My device is a Samsung Note 8, non-rooted, I'm able to get traffic from my phone that happens on website, but not apps.